# Export crossfilter dataset to excel in dc.js

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I made a visualization page using crossfilter.js and dc.js . I want to export the filtered dataset to excel. Is any way to do this.?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is to create another dimension and then call `dimension.top(Infinity)` to get all the records (sorted by that dimension's key).

Jacob Rideout created a pull request for a new method to do just this without the overhead, but it was not accepted (doesn't look like it was rejected either ;):

https://github.com/square/crossfilter/pull/95

But I doubt you will notice any performance penalty for creating the extra dimension.  (Please comment on that PR if you do!)

Comment: is there a more full example of how to use this dimension.top(Infinity) call? I try but i keep getting errors chart.Top is not a function etc im not sure where to call the top function

Comment: In referring to the [top function on the dimension object](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_top). Not the chart. You create one with `crossfilter.dimension()`

Answer (score 0):

```
function groupArrayAdd(keyfn) {
            var bisect = d3.bisector(keyfn);
            return function (elements, item) {
                var pos = bisect.right(elements, keyfn(item));
                elements.splice(pos, 0, item);
                return elements;
            };
        }
function groupArrayRemove(keyfn) {
            var bisect = d3.bisector(keyfn);
            return function (elements, item) {
                var pos = bisect.left(elements, keyfn(item));
                if (keyfn(elements[pos]) === keyfn(item))
                    elements.splice(pos, 1);
                return elements;
            };
        }
function groupArrayInit() {
            return [];
        }

var facts = crossfilter(data);  //pass your mater dataset here.
var filteredRows = facts.groupAll().reduce(
  groupArrayAdd(dc.pluck('shift')),
  groupArrayRemove(dc.pluck('shift')),
  groupArrayInit}
);
```

**filteredRows.value()** will give you the crossfilted data. Every time the data is filteded, this function will give automatically five the filted output which you can use to export to excel using any jquery plugin.

Another way to find out filtered data is using below dc function:
**dimension.top(Infinity)**